# Can a blocked contact see any number changes?

Tags: adb, notifications, contacts, security, viber-messenger

I would like to ask, whether a blocked contact will receive an information,if I change my Viber phone number? 
Is it possible to make the change by only informing a selected group of contacts or everyone I had previous communication with, will get the notification of me changing the number?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will not notice it unless they try to make contact with you after it is done. But things can become awkward if you are both a part of the same group chat. You won’t see their messages but they will see yours. And as a rule, if they are blocked, they won't see any changes of yours.